# PHP Syntax error issue, display title correctly using parameters

Tags: php

I have a php Code as below but unable to display title with correct php value
For instance on standalone basis it displays correct data as

```
$this->CatName; - Displays category

$this->prodDet->prod_name; - Displays Product Name

$this->prodDet->v_location; - Displays Location
```

I want to create a combined title as

```
Used <catname> <prod_name> for sale in <v_location>

Like
Used Fisher Milk Bottle for sale in Capetown
```

But when i modify code in

```
  $title = 'Used' ($this->CatName $this->prodDet->prod_name) 'for Sale in' ($this->prodDet->v_location);
```

It shows syntax error and does not work

Here is complete code

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.view');




/**
* Prepares the document
*
* @return void
*
* @throws Exception
*/
protected function _prepareDocument()
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menus = $app->getMenu();
    $title = null;

    $menu = $menus->getActive();

    if ($menu) {
        $this->params->def('page_heading', $this->params->get('page_title', $menu->title));
    } else {
        $this->params->def('page_heading', JText::_('COM_USEDCAR_DEFAULT_PAGE_TITLE'));
    }

    $title = $this->params->get('page_title', '');

    if (empty($title)) {
        $title = $app->get('sitename');
    } elseif ($app->get('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 1) {
        $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $app->get('sitename'), $title);
    } elseif ($app->get('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 2) {
        $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $title, $app->get('sitename'));
    }

    $title = $this->CatName;
    $this->document->setTitle($title);
}
?>
```

Can any one help how to display correct title

Comment: post the syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concatenation(`.`) operator there like below:-

```
$title = 'Used '.($this->CatName.' '.$this->prodDet->prod_name).' for Sale in '.($this->prodDet->v_location);
```

Note:- Also add spaces in between variables and string so that output look bit good.(I have already did that in my solution)

Reference:-[String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: @Ruchika  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 5):

Use the concatenation operator `.` , read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

change

```
$title = 'Used' ($this->CatName $this->prodDet->prod_name) 'for Sale in' ($this->prodDet->v_location);
```

to

```
$title = 'Used' . ($this->CatName .' '.$this->prodDet->prod_name). 'for Sale in' . ($this->prodDet->v_location);
```

Comment: Great thanks - able to almost work, but output coming as UsedFisherMilk Bottlefor Sale inCapetown , how to correct it with proper gap as Used Fisher Milk Bottle for Sale in Capetown

Comment: @Ruchika: dear you have to put space like `'Used '` and `' for sale in '`

Comment: Appreciate, Just a more - how to create space in between catname and prod_name like coming as FisherMilk Bottle - where Fisher is catname and Milk Bottle is prod_name.

Comment: @Ruchika:  modify like this `$this->CatName . '     ' . $this->prodDet->prod_name`